# Helm 3 support in terraform

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

Is Terraform provides support for Helm 3 ? 
I have find many discussion in the community forum but didn't find any solution that weather terraform make deployment using helm 3

Comment: There is this open PR on the Helm provider: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-helm/pull/378

Comment: @ydaetskcoR thanks for answering my question. 
Is there is any other adhoc method through which we can use helm3 in terraform ?

Comment: You could shell out via a provisioner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helm 3 support was introduced in v1.0.0 of the Terraform helm provider.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-helm/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Comment: helm 3 is missing here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm